# How to add the data in the realm database?

Tags: android, realm

I am new to realm , my issue is how to add the two different data example(in sql database two different tables are created to add the two diffrent data) like wise how can i add the two data in realm database.

```
 public void addData(final RealmPhoneCallLogs phoneCallLog){
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                     RealmPhoneCallLogs phoneCallLogs = realm.createObject(RealmPhoneCallLogs.class);
                                     phoneCallLogs.setId(phoneCallLog.getId());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setStartTime(phoneCallLog.getStartTime());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setActualStartTime(phoneCallLog.getActualStartTime());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setCallDuration(phoneCallLog.getCallDuration());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setCallRecords(phoneCallLog.getCallRecords());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setCallStatus(phoneCallLog.getCallRecords());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setEndTime(phoneCallLog.getEndTime());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setNumber(phoneCallLog.getNumber());
                                     phoneCallLogs.setCallType(phoneCallLog.getCallType());
                                 }
                             }
    );
}
```

The above data is added into the database.

```
 public void addImportant(final RealmPhoneCallLogs importantPhonecallLog){
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmPhoneCallLogs importantCalls = realm.createObject(RealmPhoneCallLogs.class);
            importantCalls.setId(importantPhonecallLog.getId());
            importantCalls.setStartTime(importantPhonecallLog.getStartTime());
            importantCalls.setActualStartTime(importantPhonecallLog.getActualStartTime());
            importantCalls.setCallDuration(importantPhonecallLog.getCallDuration());
            importantCalls.setCallRecords(importantPhonecallLog.getCallRecords());
            importantCalls.setCallStatus(importantPhonecallLog.getCallRecords());
            importantCalls.setEndTime(importantPhonecallLog.getEndTime());
            importantCalls.setNumber(importantPhonecallLog.getNumber());
            importantCalls.setCallType(importantPhonecallLog.getCallType());

        }
    });
}
```

How can i add the data into database.If i add the data means it is added in the existing object created in databse.How can i add this in separate table in database.

Comment: Hello. @prabha-karan It seems `RealmPhoneCallLogs` instance uses for every call log. In this case, `RealmPhoneCallLog` should be a better name. You can make separate model such as `PhoneCallLog` and `ImportantCallLog` or you can make two models for normal calls and important calls and they include `RealmList<RealmPhoneCallLog>` for call logs..

Comment: @Dalinaum when i created a two model class the error is occurring

Comment: Why not just add a `important` boolean field? Also, what is your Realm version?

Comment: Tkhs for your answer, i solved it